# MongoDB and Laravel 4

Tags: mongodb, rest, laravel-4, crud, database

I need to create CRUD Laravel 4 application using MongoDB as a database. I have experience of Laravel but don't know how to use mongoDB with it.
Can anyone give me some tutorials or tips that can help me to start?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Use this jessengers library](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB)
which makes Mongo very simple to use in mongoDb.
Integrate this library and use simply laravel query builder or ORM for CRUD.